# Display arabic characters with weka

Tags: csv, classification, weka

I've a `CSV` file with statuses written in Arabic, but they appear in form of question marks, I want to convert this file to `arff`. I'm wondering if in the `arff` file these characters will be displayed correctly or not. How can I do the classification in this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with UTF-8 characters in WEKA when using ARFF format.

I switched to the [XRFF format](http://weka.wikispaces.com/XRFF) instead which allows for explicit encoding decleration instead and this solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the `CSV` file is saved with `UTF-8` encoding before loading it to Weka or converting it to `arff`. You might try an text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)